# Help with Paraffin wax

Tags: experimental-chemistry

I am trying so hard to figure out what I am missing or what I need to use to make a lava lamp in a bottle with no heat and is safe?

Ingredients below are specifically for a lava lamp which includes use with heat;

Based on patents, new articles, and user research the original 60's formula is expected to contain distilled water, 38% by mass; chlorinated paraffin, 36%; low molecular weight polyethylene glycol, 13%; kerosene 7%; and microcrystalline wax, 6%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lava lamp is based on different thermal dilation of liquids, The organic phase dilates with temperature more and at some temperature switches from more dense to less dense.

To have the threshold temperature lower, without need of heating, you need to make water based phase somewhat denser, e.g. by dissolving the table salt.

But the particular salt concentration has to be determined experimentally.